# Infinite scroll on tableView placed inside a UIViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am very new to Swift and for the last few days I have been trying to figure out how I can implement infinite scroll in tableView which is placed inside a ViewController. All the examples I have found are based on TableViewController but my tableView is placed inside a ViewController.

Actually I am using the library MMDrawerLayout to get a left and right sliding menu so need to use a ViewController. Please some one guide me in the right direction. Any code or sample projects will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all drag and drop tableview into your viewController in storyBoard after that create an Outlet for your tableview like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

And add your tableArray:

```
var items: [String] = ["We", "Heart", "Swift"]
```

After that add `UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate` at your class declaration and it look like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

 //Your code
}
```

After that conform dataSource and deleget to self in your `viewDidLoad` method and add thi line in it:

```
self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

After that your method will be:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}
```

After that add required method of `UITableViewDataSource` as shown below:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

For more Info follow [THIS](https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

To Add infinity indicator view in bottom of your `UITableView` then followed the following things.

**Step 1** : Add following method in your current class.

```
func infinityScrollView() {

        var bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        var width = bounds.size.width
        var height = bounds.size.height


        var footerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 44))
        footerView.backgroundColor=UIColor.greenColor()

        var actInd: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        actInd.center = CGPointMake(width/2 , 22)
        actInd.color = UIColor.redColor()

        footerView.addSubview(actInd)

        YOUR_TABLEVIEW_OBJECT.tableFooterView = footerView;

    }
```

**Step 2** : Called the above method from `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        self.infinityScrollView()
    }
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: @bably, let me know if you need somethings else.